# MySQL Case in Select Statement with LIKE operator

Tags: mysql, case

Is it possible to combine the `CASE` statement and the `LIKE` operator in a MySQL `SELECT` statement?

For Example, I am trying to query a database that stores data in a single column in either one of two formats (this is awful and hurts my head, but I cant change the data so it is what it is.). So sometimes the column `numbers` would have data like "6901xxxxxxxx" and sometimes it would have data like "91xxxxxxxxxxx".

What I would like to do is query the data like so -

```
SELECT
    CASE digits
      WHEN LIKE "6901%" THEN substr(digits,4)
      WHEN LIKE "91%" THEN substr(digits,2)
    END as "digits",
FROM raw
```

This obviously doesn't work but Im hoping its possible.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Using the second form of [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) should work:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN digits LIKE '6901%' THEN substr(digits,4)
    WHEN digits LIKE '91%' THEN substr(digits,2)
  END as digits
FROM raw
```

Furthermore, you have a stray comma at the end of your `SELECT`.

Comment: +1: `CASE column WHEN...` format is only good for exact matches; have to use this format for partial matches.

Comment: Ding ding ding, wrong form of case. Thanks a ton guys, my desk/forehead are grateful.

Comment: Because the link to the documentation doesn't work any more, here is the current one https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
SELECT
    CASE true
      WHEN digits LIKE "6901%" THEN substr(digits,4)
      WHEN digits LIKE "91%" THEN substr(digits,2)
    END as "digits",
FROM raw
```

Comment: +1: I tested, this works.  MySQL ignores the "true"; I thought it would trigger a syntax error.  Still, I wouldn't add "true" in there if it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps use `LEFT()`?

```
SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN LEFT(digits, 4) = '6901' THEN substr(digits,4)
      WHEN LEFT(digits, 2) = '91' THEN substr(digits,2)
    END 
FROM raw
```

Should be more performant than the `LIKE`.

Comment: The LIKE in this example is only wildcarding the right side, so an index could be used but I don't believe that LEFT/INSTR could use an index.  +1 for an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of digits is constant, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT IF(digits > 919999, MOD(digits, 100), MOD(digits, 10000) FROM raw
```

Add `0`'s to match your actual number of digits.