# Showing partial searched text used in like as a column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Is there a way to show the "extra" of the partial text used in a like for a column value?
I'm searching something like this:

```
    SELECT c.Id, mpll.`provider_reference_code` AS 'SKU'
FROM master_price_list_line mpll 
JOIN container c ON mpll.`id_container` = c.`id_container`
WHERE mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '274119%' OR
mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '274114%' OR
mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '265501%' OR
mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '284205%' OR
mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '285207%' OR
mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '275601%' OR
mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '285202%' OR
mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '285200%'
```

And the result i need to be shown like this:

```
Full result  | Partial result
someValue23  | 23
someValue26  | 26
someVaule333 | 333
....
someValueXXX | XXX
```

The main problem is that in my DB i have products that contains an SKU number.
There are groups of products that contain an equal begining of the full SKU number, something like 100023, 100024, 100025 and what i need to know is to compare the products i have in my DB with a list in an excel to find out which products are not in the DB so my idea was to split the distinct part of the SKU and search for the ones that aren't on the DB.

EDIT: I have replaced the sample query with a real one to get a better sample.
The like's amount may vary.

Comment: if you can come up with a rule that tells mysql how to split up your "full result" into the partial, then yes. but note that if you're doing this sort of thing frequently, and/or are using that partial value in where/join clauses, then you'd be better off splitting the value off into its own dedicated field.

Comment: are the strings you are searching for always going to be a uniform length?

Comment: Yes, the lenght is 6

Comment: so you can use `SUBSTRING(col1,7)` to get the string after the strings you are searching

Answer (score 1):

You could use [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to replace the search string with '', as in `REPLACE(col1, someValue, '') AS partial_result`

Or do a `RIGHT(col1, LENGTH(col1)-LENGTH(someValue))` since your search is only a "begins with" one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SUBSTRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to get the value after *someValue* length

```
SELECT col1 AS 'Full result', SUBSTRING(col1, 10) AS 'Partial result'
FROM table1
WHERE col1 LIKE 'someValue%'
```

For multiple LIKES you can use [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) ([asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579760/mysql-case-in-select-statement-with-like-operator)):

```
CASE 
WHEN mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '1%' THEN SUBSTRING(col1, 2)
WHEN mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '12%' THEN SUBSTRING(col1, 3)
WHEN mpll.`provider_reference_code` LIKE '13%' THEN SUBSTRING(col1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX`:

```
SELECT col1 AS 'Full result',
       CASE WHEN col1 LIKE 'someValue%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, 'someValue',-1) 
            WHEN col1 LIKE 'otherValue%' THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(col1, 'otherValue',-1) 
       END AS 'Partial result'
FROM table1
WHERE col1 LIKE 'someValue%' OR col1 LIKE 'otherValue%'
```

If the substrings by which you are searching are not of uniform length, then you should place them in descending length order in the `CASE` expression.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d89a7/2)

Comment: The problem with that is that 'someValue' may change